# What does `FPSManager.lastticks` stand for in SDL_gfx?

Tags: sdl, sdl-gfx

I'm having trouble finding documentation on SDL_gfx, and I can't figure this out. I've managed to use SDL_gfx to automatically cap the framerate, and I it's working a lot better than my manual attempt (combining `SDL_Delay` and `SDL_Getticks`).

Now I've been trying to learn more about it, and I stumbled onto something.
Here's the whole [struct](http://www.ferzkopp.net/Software/SDL_gfx-2.0/Docs/html/struct_f_p_smanager.html#a05019faae5de8486dbb69d24b24eed78):

```
typedef struct {
             Uint32 framecount;
             float rateticks;
             Uint32 lastticks;
             Uint32 rate;
     } FPSmanager;
```

Most variables in this struct are pretty straightforward, but I have no idea of what `lastticks` stands for. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To put it simply, `lastticks` is used to to store the result of calling `SDL_GetTicks()`, or in other words, the number of miliseconds that have passed since the SDL library was initialized.

This is supported by looking at the `SDL_framerate.cpp` [implementation file](http://www.koders.com/cpp/fid82C8F1608E25ECD85DAB26235A98965AAE7EF478.aspx), and noticing that every assignment to `lastticks` is as follows:

```c
manager->lastticks = SDL_GetTicks();       // Lines 23 and 81
```